# Subsetting dataframe rows based on decimals in R?

Tags: r, subset, rows

I am quite new to R and have quite a challenging Question. I have a large dataframe consisting of `110,000` rows representing high-Resolution data from a Sediment core. I would like to select multiple rows based on Depth (which is recorded in mm to 3 decimal points). Of Course, I have not the time to go through the entire dataframe and pick the rows that I Need. I would like to be able to select the rows I would like based on the decimal Point part of the number and not the first Digit. I.e. I would like to be able to subset to a dataframe where all the .035 values would be returned. I have so far tried using the `which()` function but had no luck

`newdata <- Linescan_EN18218[which(Linescan_EN18218$Position.mm.== .035),]`

Can anyone offer any hints/suggestions how I can solve this Problem. [Link to the first part of the dataframe csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGvya.png)

Comment: Do you want all the values that ARE `==0.035` or all those that finish with `0.035` (1.035, 2.035, etc.) ?

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to stack overflow
Can you please further describe what you mean with *had no luck*. Did you get an error message or an empty data.frame? 
In principle, your method should work. I have replicated it with simulated data.

```
n = 100
test <- data.frame(
                        a = 1:n,
                        b = rnorm(n = n),
                        c = sample(c(0.1,0.035, 0.0001), size = n, replace  =T)
)


newdata <- test[which(test$c == 0.035),]
```